# Accessing a DataTemplate defined in an ancestors resource

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, windows-phone-7.1.1

I'm trying to access the resources of a derived abstract class (from PhoneApplicationPage) in its children. Here is a more concrete example:

**Parent WPF**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources >
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EntryTemplateAbstract">
        <!-- some ui elements -->
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

**Child WPF**

```
<controls:Pivot ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EntryTemplateAbstract}" />
```

Duo to the nature of the DataTemplate - containing click events - I'm unable to move it into the Application resource. Although in theory this would work.

On a side note: Interestingly I cannot access the resource in either the constructor of the parent or within the child.

```
var test = base.Resources["EntryTemplateAbstract"]; /* <- always returns null */
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem. It was caused by an oversight on my part, because I forgot to call InitializeComponent() in the base constructor.